# Used wheels - corrosion or dried rim tape adhesive?

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel, rim-tape, corrosion

I recently bought some used Fulcrum CPX 4.5 off eBay. They seem to be in pretty good condition, the hub is fine and wheel runs true etc. However, I noticed that when I moved them I heard dust rolling about in the wheels. I pulled of the rim tape for the rear wheel and found loads of white dust (see picture bellow).

Is this corrosion of the wheel, or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Thats just the adhesive from the old rim tape.

Get a cloth and some rubbing alcohol and rub away, and it should look brand new.

Answer (score 1):

Once you clean the surface completely, rubbing alcohol, goo gone, or your favorite cleanser.. look at the surface.  Smooth = adhesive or some other junk, nothing to worry about (most likely the case).  Pitted, degraded, or another type of surface damage would mean corroded. 
Enjoy the new rims!!! =D

Comment: I assume these are aluminum rims - how would it be possible for them to get corroded?